# MapBox SDK load local MBTiles

Tags: mapbox, android, vector-tiles, sdk, openmaptiles

does anyone know how I can load local MBTiles from the device storage using the MapBox SDK?

The vector Tiles come from this Website: https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/planet/

The same page offers Android Source Code which contains a solution for my problem but I don't want to pay over 500$.

https://openmaptiles.com/mobile-app/

Quote: "We have extended the Mapbox SDKs (C++) with the ability to load the map tiles from local MBTiles files that are either bundled with the app or downloaded by the user. "

I don't want to use a local web server for this.

Comment: Set up your own tile server with your mbtiles. https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl